# Unix script that will recursively look for specific names

Tags: recursive

Trying to find a Unix script that will recursively look for directories/files that contain in their name " backup ", "back" etc. or more than 6 numbers, so it can find those that have a date. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?? Where did you look?

Comment: You probably won't find such a script because your task seems to be handlable by `find` which is a standard command on most Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 4):

A command that will look for names in the current directory or below that contains the words `back` (which includes `backup`), or that contains at least 6 consecutive digits, and print the pathnames of these.

```
find . \( -name '*back*' -o -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*' \) -print
```

To do something with these files or directories, do so with `-exec` from `find`:

```
find . \( -name '*back*' -o -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*' \) -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # code that uses "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

If you want the names to have six digits *anywhere* rather than consecutively, change the pattern `*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*` to `*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*`.

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: A quick note for the OP - note that this answer includes spaces after the parentheses and before the escape characters. If you omit those spaces, you'll get an "invalid expression" error.

Comment: I have another question: what if I want to find files that have at least 4 consecutive digits in their name? Also, thanks for the great response!

Comment: Also, if I want to find files that contain " name_05032020 " or " name.05032020 " does it look like this : -name ' *.* *[0-9][0-9][0-9[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]]" ? I'm sorry if it's completely wrong, I'm still learning :D

Comment: @Edd That should be self evident, use `*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*`. Each `[0-9]` matches exactly one single digit.

Comment: @Edd To match a dot or an underscore, use `[._]`. so `[._][0-9]` would match a dot or an underscore followed immediately by a digit.

Comment: @Edd You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry, I meant that I may not know how many digits there are in the name, so I want the script to find me files with at least 4 digits. Also, sorry if these questions are basic/stupid.

Comment: @Edd If you _only_ want names with at least four digits, use `find . -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*'`